# After save of EditForm.aspx take user to custom list view?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, list-view

Presently I have configured multiple filtered views of the same list for different users.  When the user opens and edits a list item then Saves that list item SharePoint takes them back to the **default** list view instead of their custom filtered view. I am attempting to get SharePoint to take the user back to the view from which they started, a the custom filtered view that only shows items related to their interests.  Does anyone have any idea how to do this?  Help as always would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which SharePoint version you are using?

Comment: I am using sharepoint 2010 server

Answer (score 1):

**Solution1**

On Edit Item Click open the EditForm as follows

```
http://site/lists/listname/editform.aspx?Source=http://site/list/listname/viewname.aspx
```

After save it will redirect back to `http://site/list/listname/viewname.aspx`

**Solution2**

Update Default Edit Form aspx file and add logic to redirect user back to previous page

Comment: First off thank you for answering. Now while that sounds simple enough I am not entirely certain how to access the URL associated with the edit item click so that I can append the URL with the "?source=" part.  how do I get to that?